# Product image twice on homepage : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, media-images, speedoptimization

I have two image from different path but same image on homepage.Thats causing me low speed on gitmatrix.How to fix it.[image]

Comment: After checking i find it also loading same image for hover with different path.I just disable the hover functionality and all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate the images with they correct size and dirs running :

```
 php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

This will do the effect on the cache directory also.